# How can I add a AWS cloudwatch event to a aws_lambda_function which is based on a container image with terraform?

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, cloud, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-ecr

I want to achieve that my lambda function which is based on a docker image in ecr is triggered by a scheduled cloudwatch event.

The problem is that I can not attach the *function_name* **myFunction** from the module "lambda_function_container_image" to the **aws_lambda_permission**.

It works when I have a normal lambda function like, but not with the lambda function from a image URI:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "myFunction" {
 
  function_name = "myFunction"
  role          = aws_iam_role.lambda_execution_role.arn
  handler       = "exports.handler"
  runtime       = "python3.8"
}
```

I have the following code:

**AWS CloudWatch event:**

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "every_five_minutes" {
    name = "every-five-minutes"
    description = "Fires every five minutes"
    schedule_expression = "rate(5 minutes)"
}
```

**Lambda function based on container image:**

```
module "lambda_function_container_image" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws"

  function_name = "myFunction"
  description   = "awesome function"

  create_package = false

  image_uri    = "${data.aws_caller_identity.current.account_id}.dkr.ecr${var.aws_region}.amazonaws.com/container_name"
  package_type = "Image"
}
```

**Lambda permission:**

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_cloudwatch_to_call_myFunction" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromCloudWatch"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.myFunction.function_name
  principal     = "events.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.every_five_minutes.arn
}
```

I get the following error with the current **aws_lambda_permission**:

**Error message:**

```
Error: Reference to undeclared resource
-> points to function_name in aws_lambda_permission
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference `function_name` through the `module` you are using. According to the documentation of [terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/lambda/aws/latest#outputs) the module has an output called `lambda_function_name`.

That means, that the following should work for you:

```
resource "aws_lambda_permission" "allow_cloudwatch_to_call_myFunction" {
  [...]

  function_name = module.lambda_function_container_image.lambda_function_name

  [...]
}
```

Comment: I also thought that but it wont work. Error: **Reference to undeclared resource**.  `function_name = lambda_function_container_image.myFunction` also tried `function_name = lambda_function_container_image.myFunction.function_name` . And when I try `lambda_function_container_image.lambda_function_name` i get ***Reference to undeclared resource**. I seems to be write but not work somehow.

Comment: @Schwenk can you please try `module.lambda_function_container_image.lambda_function_name`.

Comment: Works! Thats the difference how to use a function name from a **module** or a**resource**.